# Add custom cell after the creation of a handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I'm trying the Handsontable for the first time.  My requirement is this: I want to be able to add a cell after the table has been created, in which I want to customize the content using renderer methods.

My goal is to add action buttons, such as "edit, delete, etc." for each row.

It seems possible to do so when creating the table, using the `renderers`, but I really need to be able to do this later on.

Is such a feature possible with Handsontable ?  Any hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your action handlers, try calling HOT's updateSettings passing in the new options. options takes in a list of name-value pairs which can be any handsontable property that can be configured.

Comment: That's clever.  I'll try that and let you know how it went.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Using getSettings and updateSettings I was able to set additional columns and headerCols and to exactly what I needed: add a new column with my own buttons after the creation of the table.  Thank you.